# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "column_name" not found

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entities: Order, Product and Consumer:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Brick {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Order order;
    // ... getters & setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CONSUMER")
public class Consumer{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    private List<Product> products;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @MapsId
    private Consumer consumer;
}
```

the tables are like the bellow representations, containing the properties in the parentheses:
Consumer(id)

Product(id)

Order(id, product_id, consumer_id), order_id references Product(id), consumer_id references Consumer(id)

And I am sending a post request:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "products" : [
    {"id" : 1},
    {"id" : 2}
   ],
   "consumer":1
}
```

which gives me the bellow error when trying to save the order:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "PRODUCT0_.ORDER_CONSUMER_ID" not found; SQL statement:
select product0_.id as id1_0_0_, product0_.order_consumer_id as order_cu2_0_0_ from product product0_ where product0_.id=? [42122-196]
```

My repository extends CrudRepository and I am doing repository.save(dto) to save the data.

I don't know whay it is looking for that column. 
Could you guide me to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post your repository/post method which is generating the sql?

Comment: There is no `SQLGrammarException` or 'could not prepare statement' error here.

Comment: did you make the relation from Brick to Order unidirectional intentionally or you missed the one to many relation back from order to brick ?

Comment: WHy do you use `@MapsId` on consumer? `@MapsId` does the Mapping for an `@EmbeddedId`